# Approximation of partial sums and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation

We know that $$\sum_{k≥2} \frac{1}{k \log(k)} $$ diverges.
How many terms must be taken before the partial sum exceed 10?

I have know idea which theorem or what kind of a way I should take this. Any hints?

Comment: this does not make sense. if you meant what you wrote then the $k$s could cancel. can you check?

Comment: I have edited the formula for the sum. Is my edit correct?

Comment: Have you an idea what function is asymptotically equal to $$\sum_{2 \leqslant k \leqslant x} \frac{1}{k\log k}\,?$$

Comment: Since $\int_{e}^{M}\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\log\log M$, we need about $\exp(\exp 10)$ (i.e. a colossal number) terms before the partial sums exceed $10$.

Comment: I found $e^{e^{10}}-1$